Define type which references value of keys of items within array
This is long and confusing, sorry. I'm modeling a large application's architecture in TypeScript, consider the following layout:
Definition
enum ProjectKey {
  Example1 = "example1",
}

class Project<TProjectKey extends ProjectKey, TApps extends App<any, any>[]> {
  constructor(public key: TProjectKey, public apps: TApps) { }
}

class App<TName extends string, TSecrets extends Secrets = never> {
  constructor(public name: TName, public port: number, public secrets?: TSecrets = undefined){ }
}

// boolean param is whether or not the secret is required.
type Secrets = Record<string, boolean>;

Implementation
type Example1Apps = [
  App<"app1", App1Secrets>,
  App<"app2">,
];

type App1Secrets = {
  username: true;
  password: true;
  optionalSecret: false;
};

const Example1 = new Project<ProjectKey.Example1, Example1Apps>(ProjectKey.Example1, [
  new App("app1", 1234, {
    username: true,
    password: true,
    optionalSecret: false,
  }),
  new App("app2", 5678),
]);

type AllProjects = {
  [ ProjectKey.Example1 ]: typeof Example1,
};

You can see that the goal here is to define a structure of (many) projects, their apps, and each app's configuration. It creates some redundancy, sure, but the goal is strong-typing. This strongly-typed config structure is then used to build a configuration JSON which matches the structure.
For example, the config would need to define example1.app1.secrets.username = "...", but it cannot include a non-existent app or property, e.g. example1.app6... and example1.app1.secrets.someOtherSecret are invalid.
Configuration Definition
The config would look like this, and would be strongly typed:
type ClusterConfigProps = {
  [ TProjectKey in keyof AllProjects ]: ProjectConfigProps<TProjectKey>;
};

type ProjectConfigProps<TProjectKey extends ProjectKey> = {
  apps: {
    [ TApp in AllProjects[TProjectKey]["apps"][number]["name"] ]: AppConfigProps<TProjectKey, TApp>;
  };
};

// Below, how to get the app within "apps" whose name is TApp?
type AppConfigProps<TProjectKey extends ProjectKey, TApp extends AllProjects[TProjectKey]["apps"][{ name: TApp }] =
  AllProjects[TProjectKey]["apps"][{ name: TApp }] extends { secrets: infer TSecrets }
    ? AppSecretsConfigProps<TSecrets>
    : never;

type AppSecretsConfigProps<TSecrets extends Secrets> =
  TSecrets extends undefined
  ? undefined
  : {
    [ TSecretKey in keyof TSecrets ]: TSecrets[TSecretKey] extends true
    ? { encryptedValue: string }
    : { encryptedValue: string? }
  };

Configuration Implementation
const config: ClusterConfigProps = {
  example1: {
    app1: {
      secrets: {
        username: "abcd",
        password: "passw0rd",

        // This one is optional, can be included or not.
        optionalSecret: "shhh, it's optional",
      },

    // Note that app2 has no secrets (or other config), so it shouldn't be supplied.
  },

  // Other "projects"...
  }
};

See it here in the TS Playground.
The main question here is how can I constrain an array's items by some value of some key? Like I've attempted to do here ... to "select" only the app whose name is the TApp generic variable.
type X = AllProjects[TProjectKey]["apps"][{ name: TApp }]

So I would exepect:
type X = AllProjects[ProjectKey.Example1]["apps"][{ name: "app1" }]["secrets"];

To be:
"username" | "password" | "optionalSecret"

Is it possible?

Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.  The minimum necessary for us to get started without having to spend time debugging away pseudocode would be great.

I see the edit but this is still not a [mre]. If I look at your code in the TS playground it's a huge wall of errors, many of which have nothing to do with what you're asking... just like, bad TS syntax and pseudocode. It is almost certainly possible to write a utility type to extract anything you want from the type of a value, as long as that information is present in the type system. But without an actual value we can look at in an IDE, I don't know if anyone's going to be inclined to spend time and effort just to get to the starting line.

…[{ name: TApp }] makes no sense. Did you mean something like …[TApp["name"]]? I don't get the question.

@Bergi that part is clearly pseudocode, and I presume they're actually looking for something like Extract instead, but unfortunately since everything else here is also pseudocode it's very hard for me to know how to even start.

I'm rather quessing something like:
type AppNames = "app1" | "app2"; (or similar thing with string enum) and then: [{name}:{name:AppNames}]

I cleaned it up and added a TS Playground link. And the [{ name: TApp }] part is not legit, it is what I need help with.

We're almost there, I think you did not save your TS Playground link correctly.

Note that a playground link is insufficient, so all the relevant code should be here. I'm still seeing things like "Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer" errors in the code above.

(see prev comment).  Look at the approach in this playground link. Does that fully address what you're trying to do? If so I'll write an answer (after you [edit] to fix remaining issues). If not, what am I missing?

@jazzgot fixed the link, I guess you have to hit Run to update the URL, whoops.

@jcalz the code in the question and Playground link should be the same.

Right, but part of it is still invalid (you can’t use a question mark and an initializer on the same function parameter) and not what you’re asking about;  could you fix it to be a [mre]? Then look at my earlier suggestion and tell me if it’s what you’re looking for?

I updated the playground example. This is the minimum reproducible example to work from. Your other comment is missing some of the structure I need.

• Please first just change the invalid public secrets?: TSecrets = undefined to the valid public secrets?: TSecrets. That's as plain as I can say it. Or I'll do it if you want. • Then, isn't your question how to extract the union member assignable to {name: TApp}? That's the "main question" isn't it? I've shown you how to do that. If you need others to fix the other problems, then you really need to work on that [mre] for us. Is encryptedValue expected somewhere? If so, where? Or is there some other structure missing that I don't see here? Could you please [edit] to elaborate?

(see prev comment) If I keep working on it I get something like this approach although I wouldn't expect this to be the cleanest solution. It really looks like you don't have a [mre] here. Most of the stuff I fixed in there seems like typos or conceptual errors about what you're asking. The goal of the question is something like "how do I select X out of a list like [A, B, X, Z] or a union like A | B | X | Z", and that can be done with Extract. Everything else seems like a digression from this, or too wide in scope for a single SO question. Please [edit] to fix.

Updated the playground. I'm not intentionally leaving issues in like the public secrets?... you pointed out. It didn't show as wrong due to the other errors, so I missed it. My main question is at the very bottom where each app is devined in config, how do I extract/enforce app1 which came from TName in App? It's hard to explain, I hope that makes sense.

If your example has so many errors that you can miss errors, you should fix them. A [mre] would look like this where you say "how do I get type X = " the way I want it? I showed you how to do that here. But you said it's missing structure, even though that's not your main question, and the code I cut out has problems unrelated to that main question, like the syntactic errors that hide other problems. I fixed all of those and showed you this. I don't know what else I can do here other than repeat myself. What to do?

@jcalz thanks for the feedback. Yes, your latest playground solution works! I was missing / wasn't aware of Extract. Thank so for your patience. I hope you'll submit an answer so I can accept.

All right, but first, maybe you can [edit] the question to be a [mre]? My latest playground solution is the same one I showed before, and the solution is fixing a bunch of errors unrelated to the "main question", whose answer is essentially "use Extract". The question is not in a great state to be answered as written because I'd have to go into lots of detail about why, for example, if you iterate over {[ TApp in AllProjects[TProjectKey]["apps"][number]["name"]]: ⋯} then no matter what it will require an app2 property. Suppressing that because it's empty is out of scope for the q.

See prev comment. I'm happy to make the edit myself, to look like this version where the answer is [this version]. You could, of course, use my later solution in your actual use case, but that's not the same as getting a SO question and answer pair for future readers.
